# Is there a way I can remove the action name from my actions response in Hasura?

Tags: graphql, hasura

I attempted to use response transformation in Hasura to extract the response_body from an action response. However, the action response is structured as follows

```
1. 
{
  "action_name": {
      response_body
  }
}
```

My desired outcome is to obtain the response_body without the action_name key, like this:

```
2. 
{
  response_body
}
```

Using response transform {{$body}} you get the 1.
When I attempt to access {{$body.action_name}} in the response transformation, it results in an error, as described below:

```
{
    "code": "unexpected",
    "error": "Response Transformation Failed",
    "internal": [
        {
            "error_code": "Attribute Error",
            "message": "'Object' has no attritubte 'action_name'.",
            "source_position": {
                "end_column": 17,
                "end_line": 0,
                "start_column": 1,
                "start_line": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "path": "$"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When sending optional argument or parameter, you have to send empty value like "" when it transformed to other format it should have to get attribute example

```
type Mutation{
 login(username:string,password:String}) :loginoutput
}
```

transformation

```
{
    "username": {{$body.input.username}},
     "password": {{$body.input.password}}
}
```

since your problem happened when your arguments are optional
like

```
mutation {
  login(username:"user"){
    hasura_access_token
  }
}
```

this fails to transform password so always if you used transformation every optional argument should be sent at least send with empty string

```
mutation {
  login(username:"user",password:""){
    hasura_access_token
  }
}
```